# AJAX On Keyup Search Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wrote a AJAX search function which grabs the keyword values on key up and fires off the script. My goal is to have it populate the content area every key reordering the results to be in ABC order.

Instead what's happening is the first key fires off and the top result is always this

```
*ENGRAVING
```

then the rest of the values under it are in no specific order that I can tell.

I think this has to do with escaping characters?

Any help would be appreciated. Please help me get this to function so as a user searches the content area reorders itself being in order based on the keyword being searched up to the value that has been entered at that time.

On page load 5 results are added to the page then on page scroll more results are added to the page like this,

```
var assetPath = "<?php echo $assetPath ?>";
var searchPath = "<?php echo $searchPath ?>"; 

function displayRecords(lim, off) {
  jQuery.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          async: false,
          url: assetPath,
          data: "limit=" + lim + "&offset=" + off,
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
            $('#loader_image').show();
          },
          success: function(html) {
            $("#productResults").append(html);
            $('#loader_image').hide();
            if (html === "") {
             $("#loader_message").html('<button data-atr="nodata" class="btn btn-default" type="button">No more records.</button>').show();
            } else {
             $("#loader_message").html('Loading... Please wait <img src="http://www.example.com/monstroid/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/LoaderIcon.gif" alt="Loading">').show();
            }
            window.busy = false;
          }
        });
}
```

Then when a user wants to search they use this form,

```
<div class="form-group pull-right">
                    <input type="text" name="itemID" id="itemID" class="search form-control" placeholder="Search product number">
            </div>
```

Then this ajax function fires off on keyup

```
$("#itemID").keyup(function (){
    var itemID = $(this).val();
    var url = searchPath;
    $.ajax({
        type  : "GET",
        async : false,
        url   : url,
        data  : "itemID=" + encodeURIComponent(itemID),
        cache : false,
        success: function(html) {
              $('#loader_image').hide();
           $( "#productResults" ).replaceWith( html );

              if (html === "") {
                  $("#loader_message").html('<p>There were no results that match your search criteria</p>').show();
              } else {
                  $("#loader_message").html('Searching... Please wait <img src="http://www.example.com/monstroid/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/LoaderIcon.gif" alt="Loading">').show();
              }
              window.busy = false;
        }
      });
});
```

which runs this script at searchPath as the path variable

```
require_once ('Dbconfig.php');
  $sql=" SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory WHERE wuno_product like '%".$itemID."%' OR wuno_alternates like '%".$itemID."%' ORDER BY wuno_product ";

  try {
  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
  foreach ($results as $res) {
    echo '<tr class="invent">';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_product'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_alternates'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_description'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_onhand'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_condition'] . '</td>';  
    echo '</tr>';   
  }
}
```

The initial data populates perfectly in order from what is in the database. So I do not see why there would be problems for this function if it is a escaping situation.

Also the initial data is paginated. Would this cause a problem with the second query? I was thinking maybe since there is so much data it's all being appended to the content instead of replacing it. Maybe the jquery is conflicting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try introducing the timeout for your AJAX call. Move your AJAX JS into a separate function first:

```
function get_search_results(event) {
    var itemID = $(event.target).val();
    var url = searchPath;
    $.ajax({
        type  : "GET",
        async : false,
        url   : url,
        data  : "itemID=" + encodeURIComponent(itemID),
        cache : false,
        success: function(html) {
              $('#loader_image').hide();
           $( "#productResults" ).replaceWith( html );

              if (html === "") {
                  $("#loader_message").html('<p>There were no results that match your search criteria</p>').show();
              } else {
                  $("#loader_message").html('Searching... Please wait <img src="http://www.example.com/monstroid/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/LoaderIcon.gif" alt="Loading">').show();
              }
              window.busy = false;
        }
      });
}
```

Then add it to your `keyup` handler:

```
$("#itemID").keyup(function (){
    setTimeout(get_search_results, 200);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am going to start now.

Comment: When I get the html in console.log it is the results from the query first one being the *ENGRAVING. The keyword being taken from the form is outputting each letter as a different query for each keyup. so  a ab abc and so on. Essentially it appears the problem is with the php query. But I don't get why that is not working. Maybe its showing me the opposite side of the results? so if i put it in order its showing me the back end of the order instead of the front? Does my php query look ok to you?

Comment: Is the "ENGRAVING" string *everything* you receive from the backend? Without TR and TD tags? In this case, I suspect that something else outputs this and stops the application *before* your SQL-selecting backend is triggered. If not, more info is needed. The SQL-selecting PHP backend looks legit to me.

Comment: no sir, that is just always the first result at the top of the list. the dom fills with results all wrapped in tr tds but its always the same results

Comment: Ok so I used DESC to see what was on the back side of the new list. It is wwwYYZ as the first letter of the end. Which means it is indeed putting it in order ABC. I think the problem is that on the initial load it is start the query but it does not reload again. The request keeps sending the data to the php file but it only loads in the first response. And then does not continue to update the data as I keep typing in the input field. So I think the problem here is figuring out why the data wont keep updating every keey up

Comment: Try echo-ing your $sql without the TR/TD output, then view it in your console log after each keyup. The point is to see the actual SQL you're creating for the backend with your $itemID. Also, try `keypress` event instead of `keyup`. *(On a slightly related note, you shouldn't pass $itemID straight into $sql - use parameters in the `$stmt->execute()` instead.)*

Comment: Hmm Im not sure what you mean.  Ill google it and read up on parameters for PDO

Comment: It probably is not related to the issue you're experiencing, but you have to do this in order to avoid SQL injections. PHP doco uses good examples here: http://au2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Oh ok thanks man. Yes when I was done getting this working I was going to spend a lot of time making sure its secure. I am 99% sure the problem is the loading of the html. When I search for a result it tells me if there are not results in the database that match my query but then if i delete and keep typing something else it follows me to the last letter its just not updating the content in the area. Would you please look at my ajax query and tell me why its not continuing to update the content every key stroke?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103552/discussion-between-sergey-vidusov-and-wuno).